# Java file transfer through sockets

Tags: java, socket, network-file-transfer

I am making a program that transfers files from one client to another. Right now I am just working on sending the file to the server and then later I will work on transferring it to the other client.
Here is my client class*:

```java
public class Client implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    private InputStream input;
    private OutputStream output;
    private PrintWriter printer;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    private boolean running = true;
    private long ping = System.nanoTime() / 1000000;

    public Client(String address) {
        String host = address.substring(0, address.indexOf(":"));
        int port = Integer.parseInt(address.substring(address.indexOf(":") + 1));
        System.out.println("Attempting to connect to " + host + ":" + port);
        try {
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
            printer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            output = socket.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Successfully connected!");
            running = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            running = false;
            System.out.println("Failed to connect.");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            ;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!running)
            return;
        String str;
        printer.println("ping");
        try {
            while (running && (str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                handle(str);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.close();
    }

    public void handle(String str) {
        if (str.equals("ping")) {
            send("pong");

        } else if (str.equals("pong")) {
            ping = ((System.nanoTime() / 1000000) - ping) / 2;
            System.out.println("Ping: " + ping + "ms");
            File file = new File("./res/" + "send.zip");
            send("pong");

            for (int lcv = 0; lcv < 1; lcv++) {
                sendFile(file);
                wait(1000);
            }

        }
        if (str.equals(SocketKey.CLOSE_CONNECTION)) {
            running = false;
            printer.println(SocketKey.CLOSE_CONNECTION);
        }
    }

    public void sendFile(File file) {
        long startTime = (System.nanoTime() / 1000000);
        long fileSize = file.length();
        send("new_file:[" + file.getName() + "][" + fileSize + "]");
        System.out.println("Name: " + file.getName() + " Size: " + Util.readableFileSize(fileSize));
        System.out.print("Transferring file");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(file);
            int count, totalCount = 0;
            double perc = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                totalCount += count;
                if (perc < ((double) totalCount) / fileSize) {
                    System.out.print(".");
                    perc += .1;
                }
                do {
                    output.write(bytes, 0, count);

                } while (waitFor(".", 1000) == null);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String str;
        try {
            while (running && (str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (str.equals("Complete.") || str.equals("Failed.")) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "\nFile successfully sent! (" + ((System.nanoTime() / 1000000) - startTime) + "ms)");
                    break;
                } else
                    handle(str);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String[] waitFor(String string, long ms) {
        String str;
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        long startTime = (System.nanoTime() / 1000000);
        try {
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (str.equals(string) || !running)
                    break;
                else if ((System.nanoTime() / 1000000) - startTime < ms)
                    return null;
                else
                    strings.add(str);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] ret = new String[strings.size()];
        for (int lcv = 0; lcv < strings.size(); lcv++)
            ret[lcv] = strings.get(lcv);
        return ret;
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void send(Object... objects) {
        String output = "";
        for (Object obj : objects) {
            output += obj.toString();
        }
        printer.println(output);
    }

    public void wait(int milliseconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
//      startUI();
        Client client = new Client("localhost:1123");
        new Thread(client).start();
//      File file = new File("./res/" + "");
//      client.sendFile(file);

    }
}
```

here is my server class*:

```java
public class Server {

    public static boolean running = true;
    public static List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    public static List<Connection> clients = new ArrayList<Connection>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1123);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Can't setup server on this port number. ");
        }

//      Make a thread that detects if the thread count has changed and redistribute that info

        while (running) {
            try {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("New connection from " + socket.getInetAddress());
                Thread newThread = new Thread(new Connection(socket));
                threads.add(newThread);
                newThread.start();

                Thread.sleep(10000);
                break;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Can't accept client connection. ");
            }
        }
        serverSocket.close();
    }

}
```

and finally here is my class that handles each connection*:

```java
public class Connection implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    private InputStream input;
    private PrintWriter printer;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    private boolean running = true;
    private long ping = System.nanoTime() / 1000000;

    public Connection(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            input = socket.getInputStream();
            printer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Can't get socket input/output stream.");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String str;
        connect();
        try {
            while (Server.running && running && (str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                handle(str);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        close();
    }

    private void connect() {

    }

    private void handle(String str) {
        if (str.equals("ping")) {
            send("pong");
        } else if (str.equals("pong")) {
            ping = (System.nanoTime() / 1000000) - ping;
            System.out.println("Ping: " + ping + "ms");
            send(SocketKey.CLOSE_CONNECTION);
        }

        if (str.equals(SocketKey.CLOSE_CONNECTION)) {
            running = false;
            System.out.println("Server Closing.");
            printer.println(SocketKey.CLOSE_CONNECTION);
        }

        if (str.startsWith("new_file:")) {
            receiveFile(str);
        }
    }

    public boolean receiveFile(String str) {

        System.out.print("Receiving file");
        long startTime = (System.nanoTime() / 1000000);

        String fileName = str.substring(str.indexOf("[") + 1, str.indexOf("]"));
        fileName = checkFileName(
                fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")) + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")));
        long fileSize = Long.parseLong(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("[") + 1, str.lastIndexOf("]")));
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream("./res/" + fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found. ");
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];

        int count;
        long totalCount = 0, totalToDo = fileSize;
        double perc = 0;
        try {
            while ((count = input.read(bytes, 0, (int) Math.min(bytes.length, fileSize))) != -1 && 0 < fileSize) {
                fileSize -= count;
                output.write(bytes, 0, count);
                totalCount += count;
                if (perc < ((double) totalCount) / totalToDo) {
                    System.out.print(".");
                    perc += .1;
                }
                send(".");
            }
            output.close();
            long tdiff = ((System.nanoTime() / 1000000) - startTime);
            System.out.println("\nFile successfully saved. (" + tdiff + "ms)");
            System.out.println("Average transfer speed: " + Util.readableFileSize(totalToDo / (tdiff / 1000)) + "/s");
            Util.printFileInfo(new File("./res/" + fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            send("Complete.");
            return false;
        }
        send("Complete.");
        return true;
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            reader.close();
            printer.close();

            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String checkFileName(String fileName) {
        if (new File("./res/" + fileName).exists()) {
            if (fileName.contains("_")) {
                String hex = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("_") + 1, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
                return checkFileName(fileName.replace("_" + hex + ".",
                        "_" + Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(hex, 16) + 1) + "."));

            }
            return checkFileName(fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")) + "_1"
                    + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")));

        } else {
            return fileName;
        }

    }

    public void send(Object... objects) {
        String output = "";
        for (Object obj : objects) {
            output += obj.toString();
        }
        printer.println(output);
    }
}
```

Here is my Util class in case it is needed:

```java
public class Util {
    public static final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    public static final int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth(), height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();

    public static String lower_alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", upper_alphabet = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
            digits = "0123456789", hex = "0123456789abcdef";

    public static JFrame getDefaultFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("DataDrop");
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;
    }

    public static boolean isDigit(String s) {
        return digits.contains(s);
    }

    public static boolean areDigits(String s) {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray())
            if (!isDigit(c + ""))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isHex(String s) {
        return hex.contains(s);
    }

    public static boolean areHex(String s) {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray())
            if (!isHex(c + ""))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isLetter(String s) {
        return lower_alphabet.contains(s) || upper_alphabet.contains(s);
    }

    public static boolean areLetters(String s) {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray())
            if (!isLetter(c + ""))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static String readableFileSize(long size) {
        if (size <= 0)
            return "0";
        final String[] units = new String[] { "B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
        int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size) / Math.log10(1024));
        return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size / Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
    }

    public static void printFileInfo(File file) {
        String fileName = file.getName();
        System.out.println("File info:");
        System.out.println("    File Name     : " + fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")));
        System.out.println("    File Size     : " + readableFileSize(file.length()));
        System.out.println("    File Extension: " + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")));
        System.out.println("    Full Path     : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

*I removed the getters and setters because they are just the auto-generated ones from eclipse and they have no other function.

I am unsure of the efficiency of my transfer methods and I am pretty sure it's bad practice to send both bytes and strings through the socket, but I do not know another way.

I also don't know how to send more than one file without making the thread sleep for a second. If I don't let the Thread sleep, the program eventually gets hung up because a packet gets lost somehow. I know it shouldn't be possible, but I managed to find a way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some kind wire protocol. In simplest case a triple (int length, int/enum 
 for tag/type, byte[] data). Then you will be able to differentiate between command "ping" and a sending a file with content "ping". Also look into ProtoBuf or ObjectInputStream - it is futile to try parsing objects from `toString()` output.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, could you go into a little more detail about what a triple is? I didn't learn what an enum was in my APCS class, and I have never used one.